# Rigid Body Compound Collisions

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am using the collision shape "compound". The child meshes are simplified versions of the collision mesh "compound parent". I am not sure why, but the compounds behave as if they had a force attracting them to each other.
[image]

Might be the compound children were duplicates? Thank you

EDIT:
Here is another tryout...there are specific meshes that get "glued" to each other.
[image]